# How to persist changes from developer tools for an email

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, html-email

I have an email that the app from my project sends to the customer once they successfully place an order.
I am not satisfied with the styling applied to the email.

So I opened the received email generated on my testing environment and I edited CSS styling in the Developer Tools.
How can I save these changes for this email? So that I don't have to do it from scratch each time I open the email.
I tried saving all the HTML elements from the DOM in the HTML file but that doesn't work.
When I open it again with the browser it is just a blank page.

I found some resources online for saving the changes to the project index.html file but that doesn't apply to this case with the email.
Please help :)

Comment: Start here: https://myemma.com/blog/css-in-html-emails-what-you-need-to-know-to-get-started/

Comment: You would need to locate the HTML of the email from wihtin the system that is sending it, and edit that. What system are you using?